# Hide and show multiple html elements using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have some tables here, and using this **javascript** below, I made them **hide and show** every time a user click on their **buttons**. What I want to add in to this script, is when someone click on a table's button to show-up, all the other to be hidden. Any idea how can I do this? Thank you in advance!

**This is my html code:**

```
<table id="SC1_TH_" class="header_op"><tr><td>
<div id="SC1_BSH_" onClick="SC[1]();" class="hide_button">*</div>OPTION ONE
</td></tr></table>
<div id="SC1_BO_" style="display:dlock;">BLAH BLAH</div>

<table id="SC2_TH_" class="header_cl"><tr><td>
<div id="SC2_BSH_" onClick="SC[2]();" class="show_button">*</div>OPTION ONE
</td></tr></table>
<div id="SC2_BO_" style="display:none;">BLAH BLAH</div>

<table id="SC3_TH_" class="header_cl"><tr><td>
<div id="SC3_BSH_" onClick="SC[3]();" class="show_button">*</div>OPTION ONE
</td></tr></table>
<div id="SC3_BO_" style="display:none;">BLAH BLAH</div>
```

**This is my javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var SC = [];

for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {

SC[i] = (function(i){

return function(){

var SC_TH  = document.getElementById('SC'+i+'_TH_');
var SC_BSH = document.getElementById('SC'+i+'_BSH_');    
var SC_BO  = document.getElementById('SC'+i+'_BO_');

  if (SC_BO.style.display == 'block' || SC_BO.style.display == ''){
      SC_TH.className      = 'header_cl';
      SC_BSH.className     = 'show_button';
      SC_BO.style.display  = 'none';}
else {SC_TH.className      = 'header_op';
      SC_BSH.className     = 'hide_button';
      SC_BO.style.display  = 'block';}
     }})(i);}       
</script>
```

---

EDIT: In other words, I need something to say, **if** this button that **clicking** right now is **something** all the **other** to be **hidden**!!!

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're not using for example jQuery, etc? "Accordion" style showing and hiding is a solved problem with most js libraries:  [See here](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

Comment: Yes my friend cause I **should** make my own!!! Orders you see...

Comment: Somebody ordered you to use inline Javascript instead of a framework like JQuery?

Comment: Oh yes!!! :) If you have to do with people that can't understand... You know!!!

Comment: Yikes, that's too bad. Do they realise that jquery *is* javascript? And that they are asking you to literally re-invent the wheel?

Comment: @Stephen Byrne: I think they don't but... It's just a small section and it would be better to use JavaScript instead of loading the entire jQuery library.

Comment: You'll find in time that *"loading the entire jQuery library"* is not a bad thing. It's lightweight, consists of a single file (unless you want to use UI components such as Accordion in which case there's a second file plus CSS and images), and will be cached by the browser. If you add it and start using it, you'll soon realize the error of not using such a thing.

Comment: @flem: I am not disagree with you!!! But just this time, I have to do like this!!!

Comment: You say you want to hide the tables when the button is pushed; are you sure? The buttons are *inside* the tables in your html so will also disappear when the tables are hidden; there will be no way to re-display the content.

Comment: @Stuart: I want to hide the `SC1_BO_` that is out of table not the table and what is inside!!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/mUawu/1/) with some very simple jQuery (recommended) code.

HTML:

```
<table><tr><td>
<div class="toggle-button">*</div>OPTION ONE
</td></tr></table>
<div class="toggle">BLAH BLAH</div>

<table><tr><td>
<div class="toggle-button">*</div>OPTION ONE
</td></tr></table>
<div class="toggle">BLAH BLAH</div>

<table><tr><td>
<div class="toggle-button">*</div>OPTION ONE
</td></tr></table>
<div class="toggle">BLAH BLAH</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('div.toggle').hide();
    $('.toggle-button').click(function(){
        $('div.toggle').hide();
        $(this).closest('table').next('div.toggle').show();
    });
});
```

As @StephenByrne mentioned, I also strongly recommend using an existing component such as [jQuery Accordian](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/). It takes minutes to implement and comes with a whole host of themes to chose from and is fully customisable. You could spend hours or days writing your own. Unless it's a learning exercise, it's simply a waste of time. No need to reinvent the wheel.

As you have indicated a strong push towards js-only, here's a [working js-only solution](http://jsfiddle.net/mjfeF/1/).

HTML:

```
<table id="SC1_TH_" class="header_op"><tr><td>
<div id="SC1_BSH_" onclick="toggle(this);" class="hide_button">*</div>OPTION ONE
</td></tr></table>
<div id="SC1_BO_" style="display:block;">BLAH BLAH</div>

<table id="SC2_TH_" class="header_cl"><tr><td>
<div id="SC2_BSH_" onclick="toggle(this);" class="show_button">*</div>OPTION ONE
</td></tr></table>
<div id="SC2_BO_" style="display:none;">BLAH BLAH</div>

<table id="SC3_TH_" class="header_cl"><tr><td>
<div id="SC3_BSH_" onclick="toggle(this);" class="show_button">*</div>OPTION ONE
</td></tr></table>
<div id="SC3_BO_" style="display:none;">BLAH BLAH</div>
```

JS:

```
function toggle(src) {
    var id =  src.id;
    var index = id.substring(2, 3);

    var i = 1;
    var toggleItem = document.getElementById('SC' + i.toString() + '_BO_');

    while (toggleItem != null) {
        var bShow = index == i;
        var button = document.getElementById('SC' + i.toString() + '_BSH_');
        var table = document.getElementById('SC' + i.toString() + '_TH_');

        if (bShow) {
            toggleItem.style.display = 'block';
            toggleItem.className = 'setitemclassname';
            button.className = 'setbuttonclassname';
            table.className = 'settableclassname';
        }
        else {
            toggleItem.style.display = 'none';
            toggleItem.className = 'setitemclassname';
            button.className = 'setbuttonclassname';
            table.className = 'settableclassname';
        }
        toggleItem = document.getElementById('SC' + (++i).toString() + '_BO_');
    }
}
```

Inside the `while` loop when `index == i` evaluates to `true`, you know you have the item to show. Add extra logic there to change your class names.

Comment: @ATOzTOA This is a *recommendation* and adds value to a community that may be looking for the same solution without a JS-only dependency. It's not always best to give the OP exactly what they want but also to propose better solutions.

Comment: Your example is very good my friend and thank you for your answer and you time!!! But I need something that will patch on my javascript code above...

Comment: @DNA180 See updated answer with inclusion of JS-only approach.

Comment: Your second example is working for me!!! I just need to do some corrections on how it looks when clicked or not. Thank you very much for your help!!!

Comment: @flem: Well, I don't have the knowledge to do what I said as it is now. If you have the kindness, please tell me this... How I'll "say" to this script you wrote, that if **display** is **block** take this **class** and if is not take the **other class**??? As it is now I can't imagine the syntax!!! Really thank you for your time!!!

Comment: @flem: It change style for `SC1_BO_` that contains the text "Blah Blah". I need to change `SC1_TH_` table and `SC1_BSH_` button styles!!! :)

Comment: @DNA180. Updated to include button and table.

Answer (score 1):

Just hide all of them, then show the one that should become toggled open. This script is not the elegantest solution, but integrates directly in your coding style:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    SC[i] = (function(i){
        var SC_TH  = document.getElementById('SC'+i+'_TH_'),
            SC_BSH = document.getElementById('SC'+i+'_BSH_'),
            SC_BO  = document.getElementById('SC'+i+'_BO_');

        return function(action) {
            if (!action) action = SC_BO.style.display=="none" ? "show" : "hide";

            if (action == "show") { 
                for (var i=0; i<SC.length; i++)
                    SC[i]("hide");
                SC_TH.className      = 'header_op';
                SC_BSH.className     = 'hide_button';
                SC_BO.style.display  = '';
            } else {
                SC_TH.className      = 'header_cl';
                SC_BSH.className     = 'show_button';
                SC_BO.style.display  = 'none';
            }
        };
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: @Bergi *"not the elegantest solution"*. That's the understatement of the year. We shouldn't be promoting illegible code.

Comment: @flem: Don't blame him :) He just tried to make it close to my coding style as he said!!!

Comment: @DNA180. There's no blame here, just my opinion that the code (no matter who wrote it) is not well written. This is not meant to cause offense but rather meant as constructive criticism. If you revisit this code in a year from now, you'll have no idea what it means. Those of us with more experience should not be promoting this style of coding. It's not good for us, OP, or the community. It's especially bad for those who have to support the code in the future.

Comment: @flem: I don't think the code is illegible. Correctly indented, it is quite clear what happens in the closure. The array of functions is a bit weird - at least if this is a standalone functionality - but might integrate well into some data model (which the OP might have hidden from us to make the example self-contained). Of course you are right that this type of code should not be chosen over a cleaner solution if the goal is just a simple accordion functionality.

Answer (score 1):

A [cleaner solution](http://jsfiddle.net/mjfeF/8/) involves altering your HTML a bit as well - getting rid of the `onclick` and replacing it with a class (`toggleItem`) that will allow the javascript to identify the items to be toggled. I also make sure that all the buttons have the class `button` so they can be identified.

```
<table id="SC1_TH_" class="header">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="SC1_BSH_" class="button">*</div>OPTION ONE</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="SC1_BO_" class="toggleItem">BLAH BLAH</div>
<table id="SC2_TH_" class="header">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="SC2_BSH_" class="button">*</div>OPTION ONE</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="SC2_BO_" class="toggleItem">BLAH BLAH</div>
<table id="SC3_TH_" class="header">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="SC3_BSH_" class="button">*</div>OPTION ONE</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="SC3_BO_" class="toggleItem">BLAH BLAH</div>
```

Then in the javascript:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('button'),
  toggleItems = document.getElementsByClassName('toggleItem'),
  tables = document.getElementsByClassName('header');
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].onclick = getFunction(toggle, i);
}
// getFunction is needed for reasons to do with variable scope
function getFunction(f, p) {return function() {f(p)}}
function toggle(selected) {
    for (var i = 0; i < toggleItems.length; i++) {
        toggleItems[i].style.display = i == selected ? '' : 'none';
        tables[i].className = i == selected ? 'header open' : 'header closed';
        buttons[i].className = i == selected ? 'button show' : 'button hide';
    }
}
toggle(0);  // initially show only the first one
```

(This does assume that the buttons and toggle items will be in the same order. If that is not the case you will have to revert to checking their IDs or find some other way to associate the items and buttons.)

(EDITED to include changing class of tables and buttons)